# how to add a calculated column :Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am trying to add a column (verif) to table del_licence

```
alter del_licence
add verif
as (select b.ID AS verif from vio_licence b
where exists (select key2 from del_licence where b.key1 = key2)PERSISTED
```

i have the following error: *Subquery returned more than 1 value.*

I tried to fix it by creating a view but it didn't work

Comment: Is select FIRST(key2) from del_licence where b.key1 = key2 as the subquery solving your problem?

Comment: A Calculated column can't reference another table. It can be a **scalar expression** only. If you *must* reference another table, you will need to create a scalar function, however, these come with a lot of considerations, and can have (significant) detrimental effects to the performance of your table/database.

Comment: You're not actually using SQL Server, are you?

Comment: @allmhuran yes I am using SQL server

Comment: OK, it's just that your statement has a syntax error, it's missing the word `table` after `alter`. Anyway, in addution to what Larnu said, think about what happens if your `exists` subquery returns any rows at all. Then the `select from vio_license` will return every row in that table, you are then selecting the `ID` from that result set - potentially lots and lots of `ID` values, and trying to set it as the value of `verif` for your computed column.

Comment: @allmhuran Yes I forgot to copy "table" but it was in my query.
Yes I understand now why I have this error...

Comment: @Larnu thank you, is there another way to fix the issue too ?

Comment: Other than using a scalar function? Not for a computed column. You'll likely be better off with a `VIEW` and a proper `JOIN`.